# PHP, или JavaScript, или C++, Java, Python?

Tags: алгоритм, соревнование

На экспертном форуме программистов ХэшКод задают вопросы и дают ответы разработчики на PHP, JavaScript, C++, Java, Python и других языках. Если просмотреть темы за последний месяц, то можно предположить, что те участники форума, в сообщениях которых чаще встречается слово PHP, чем JavaScript - специализируются на PHP. Те участники форума, в сообщениях которых чаще встречается слово JavaScript, чем PHP - специализируются на JavaScript, а все остальные - специализируются C++, или Java, или Python.

Итак на вход подается текст, содержащий слова на русском и английском алфавитах, включая знаки препинания. Требуется написать код на любом подходящем языке программирования, определяющий специализацию автора.

Comment: Уж не отсюда ли взяли эту задачку?
http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1612

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = 'i love java. only java java! i don\'t love javascript, c++, python or php...';
$specialization = array(
    'php' => 'PHP-разработчик',
    'javascript|js' => 'JavaScript-разработчик',
    'c\+\+' => 'C++ разработчик', // для этого и последующих двух можно сделать одно значение, но мне кажется, что это бредовато
    'java(?!script)' => 'JAVA-разработчик',
    'python' => 'Python-разработчик'
);
$specialization_col = array();
foreach(array_keys($specialization) as $value) {
    preg_match_all("/({$value})/", $string, $matches);
    $specialization_col[$value] = count($matches[0]);
};
arsort($specialization_col);
echo $specialization_col[$key] > 0 ? $specialization[key($specialization_col)] : 'C++ / Java / Python разработчик';
?>
```

Comment: ха, хитро!

Answer (score 7):

В 5 строчек на Python:

```
import sys, re, collections

cnt = collections.Counter(re.findall('\w+', sys.stdin.read().lower()))
tpl = 'You are %s programmer'

if cnt['php'] == cnt['javascript']: print(tpl % 'C++, Java or Python')
else: print(tpl % ('PHP' if cnt['php'] > cnt['javascript'] else 'JavaScript'))
```

Проверяем:

```
$ echo JavaScript круче, чем PHP! Однако Python более лаконичный язык, чем JavaScript. | python counter.py
You are JavaScript programmer
```

Answer (score 4):

**Delphi**:

```pascal
program for_tshirt;
var
  s, k : string;
  i, php, javascript : integer;
begin
  readln(s);
  k := '';
  for i := 1 to length(s) do
    if (s[i] = ' ') or (s[i] in ['a'..'z']) or (s[i] in ['A'..'Z']) then 
      k := k + upcase(s[i]);
  php := 0;
  javascript := 0;
  k := ' ' + k + ' ';
  for i := 1 to length(k) do begin
    if (length(k) - i >= 4) then 
      inc(php, ord(copy(k, i, 5) = ' PHP ')));
    if (length(k) - i >= 9) then 
      inc(javascript, ord(copy(k, i, 10) = ' JAVASCRIPT ')));
  end;
  if (php > javascript) then 
    writeln('PHP')
  else
    if (php < javascript) then 
      writeln('JavaScript')
    else
      writeln('C++ or Java or Python');
end.
```

**Python 2**:

```py
#set coding=utf-8
s = raw_input()
punct = ".,?!:\"-';"
k = ''
for i in range(len(s)):
bad = False
for j in range(len(punct)):
    if (punct[j] == s[i]):
    bad = True
if not bad:
    k = k + s[i]
else:
    k = k + ' '     
if (s.count(' PHP ') > s.count(' JavaScript ')):
    print('PHP')
elif (s.count(' PHP ') > s.count(' JavaScript ')):
    print('JavaScript')
else:
    print('C++ or Java or Python.')
```

Answer (score 4):

Python

```
import sys
import string

js = 0
php = 0
data = sys.stdin.read().lower()
words = data.split(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
for w in words:
    if w == 'php':
        php += 1
    elif w == 'javascript':
        js += 1
if js == php:
    print 'C++, Java or Python'
elif js > php:
    print 'JavaScript'
else:
    print 'PHP'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    $i     = 0;
    $max   = 0;
    $str   = "input text";
    $langs = array('PHP', 'JavaScript', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python');

    foreach($langs as $lang) {
        if(substr_count($str, $lang) > $max) {
            $max    = substr_count($str, $lang);
            $result = $lang;
        }

        if('JavaScript' == $lang) {
            $str = str_replace('JavaScript', 'JS', $str);
        }
    }

    print $lang;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен, правильно ли я понял суть задачи, но вот моё решение на `JavaScript`:

```
function count(str, sub) {
    var n = 0;
    for (str = str.toLowerCase(); str.indexOf(sub) != str.lastIndexOf(sub); n++, str = str.substr(str.indexOf(sub) + sub.length - 1));
    if (str.indexOf(sub) > -1) n++;
    return n;
}
var s = prompt('Введите сообщение пользователя', '') || '',
    php = count(s, 'php'),
    js = count(s, 'javascript');

alert('Специализация: ' + (php > js ? 'PHP' : php < js ? 'JavaScript' : 'C++, или Java, или Python') + '.');
```

Comment: @ХэшКод, зачем так много пробелов? Черезчур растянуто смотрится.

Comment: Это стандартное форматирование http://jsbeautifier.org/.

Answer (score 3):

```
#set coding=utf-8

def specialization(message):
    punctuation = ".,?!:\"-';"
    words = "".join([c for c in message if c not in punctuation]).split()
    php = javascript = other = 0
    for w in words:
        if w == "PHP":
            php += 1
        elif w == "JavaScript":
            javascript += 1
        else:
            other += 1
    if php > javascript:
        return u"PHP"
    elif javascript < php:
        return u"JavaScript"
    else:
        return u"C++, или Java, или Python"
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript

```
function qwe(str) {
    var res = [0,0,0];
    str.replace(
        /(php)|(javascript)|(java\b|python|c\+\+)/gi,
        function(s, php, js, etc) {
            php ? res[0]++ : js ? res[1]++ : res[2]++
        });
    pro = res[0]>res[1] && res[0]>res[2] ? 'PHP' : res[1]>res[2] ? 'JavaScript' : 'C++, Java or Python';
    return "You are "+ pro +" programmer.";
}

console.log(
    qwe("На экспертном форуме программистов ХэшКод задают вопросы и дают ответы разработчики на PHP, JavaScript, C++, Java, Python и других языках. Если просмотреть темы за последний месяц, то можно предположить, что те участники форума, в сообщениях которых чаще встречается слово PHP, чем JavaScript - специализируются на PHP. Те участники форума, в сообщениях которых чаще встречается слово JavaScript, чем PHP - специализируются на JavaScript, а все остальные - специализируются C++, или Java, или Python.")
);
// You are C++, Java or Python programmer.
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript + **black voodoo magic** (тернарные операторы, приоритет операторов, динамическая типизация):

```
function printFavouriteLang(/* String*/ msg){
    var m1,m2,x;
    var PHP_REG = /\s?php\s|\s?php$/ig;
    var JS_REG = /\s?javascript\s|\s?javascript$/ig;

    ((x = ((m1 = msg.match(PHP_REG)) ? m1.length : 0) - ((m2 = msg.match(JS_REG)) ? m2.length : 0)) > 0) ? console.log("php") : x == 0 ? console.log("other (java, c#, python)") : console.log("js");
}
```

Советую скопировать в консоль и поиграться с функцией.

Учтены граничные условия:

1. 0 и более токенов *php*
2. 0 и более токенов *javascript*
3. Токены в конце сообщения

З.Ы. Без объявления переменных тело функции помещается в 1 строку.

Answer (score 3):

Русскими буквами можно пренебречь, потому что названия языков программирования пишутся на английском языке. И, судя по условию, нужно брать во внимание только два слова 'php', 'javascript'.

```
var c:char;   f:text;
    slovo:string;
    php,javascript:longint;

    {процедура проверки слова}
    procedure proveri(s:string);
    begin
     if (s='php') or (s='Php') or (s='PHP') then inc(php) else
     if (s='javascript') or (s='Javascript') or (s='JAVASCTIPT') then inc(javascript);
    end;

begin

 {связываение с файлом на жёстком диске}
 assign(f,'input.txt'); reset(f);

 {обнуляем все нужные переменные}
 slovo:=''; php:=0; javascript:=0;

 {рассматривание данного текста и выбор двух нужных слов 'php' и 'javascript'}
 while not eof(f) do
 begin
  read(f,c);
  if ((c>='A') and (c<='Z')) or ((c>='a') and (c<='z')) then slovo:=slovo+c else
  if slovo<>'' then
  begin
   proveri(slovo);
   slovo:='';
  end;
 end;

 close(f);

 {основное условие}
 if php>javascript then writeln('PHP разработчик') else
 if php<javascript then writeln('Javascript разработчик') else
                        writeln('C++ / Java / Python разработчик');
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
inputStr = 'input text'.lower()
langs = ["php", "javaScript", "c++", "java", "python"]
l = []
for i in langs: l.append(inputStr.count(i))
print(langs[l.index(max(l))])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rebuild=(level)

      delta_attributes :level

      scope :moderators, lambda { where("moderator_level > ?", level) }

end
```